# Java : Building URI with fragment before query params

Tags: java, url, encoding, uribuilder

I am looking to build a URI of the type :
https://example.com/index.html#db/report/csv?token=4cec23a8a07b63c1ed74&time=1473951700000&name=GA

but what I am trying is producing incorrect results :

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("https://example.com").path("index.html#db/report/csv").queryParam("token", "4cec23a8a07b63c1ed74").queryParam("time", "1473951700000").queryParam("name", "GA").build();
```

The above is encoding the # and resulting in

https://example.com/index.html%23db/report/csv?token=4cec23a8a07b63c1ed74&time=1473951700000&name=GA

How to not encode the # and still get the desired Url.

Comment: In your URL, the path is /index.html, and there is no query param. Only one long string masquerading a path followed by query params after the hash. What do you want this URI for?

Comment: It points the user to a webpage, the pre-condition is I cannot change the link, it is a link to a third party web page, the requirement is to create the link dynamically by reading base(Uri and path/fragment) from config, and add query params dynamically.

Comment: Then do that with custom code, not with a URI builder.

Comment: Ok, String Building seems to be the way go, thanks for the help, also I wanted to understand, is the required url malformed, as no library seems to be supporting to build it?

Comment: It's not malformed. But it's using a trick to simulate a path and query params in a single-page application (probably angular based) by putting them after the hash, which is normally used to refer to an anchor inside the page.

Comment: How do you use the class UriBuilder? I am trying to build an URI myself and the IDE doesn't seem to recognize it but instead proposes me to change it to URLBuilder which I don't think is gonna work... @greperror